# How to Deploy html project using gradle in libgdx

Tags: html, gradle, libgdx

I have successfully run my html project using following command

gradlew html:superDev

And after that I run "gradlew html:dist" command .

This compiled my app to Javascript and place the resulting Javascript, HTML and asset files in the html/build/dist/ folder.

Now my question is how to use this "dist" folder to run my project on server.

I tried to upload this "dist" folder on my server and then runs it's index.html file but only superDev Refresh button appears.

Please tell me what are the steps to follow after creating the dist folder ?

Which files and folder should I upload on server ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I solved it by taking following steps:-

1. In eclipse I right click on html project and compile it using GWT compile.

2 then run the html project as web application.

3 After successfully launching of the game I copy all the folders excepts WebInf from the war folder and place them in a new folder then upload it on server.

That's it.

But through Gradle I did not get any success.

Comment: Do you know how to GWT compile in IntelliJ?

Comment: Ashley, In your project root, run the command ./gradlew html:dist (Unix) or gradlew.bat html:dist (Windows) to build.